# Convert type of std::tuple to std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

[Boost document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html) show us how to implement a type converter

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl;

template<template<class...> class A, class... T, template<class...> class B>
    struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>
{
    using type = B<T...>;
};

template<class A, template<class...> class B>
    using mp_rename = typename mp_rename_impl<A, B>::type;
```

Function of this mp_rename is convert type A to type B.

Example :

```
mp_rename<std::pair<int, double>, std::tuple>
```

equal to

```
std::tuple<int, double>
```

As far as I know

```
mp_rename<std::pair<int, double>, std::tuple>
```

call

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl;
```

After that forward to

```
template<template<class...> class A, class... T, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>
```

My question is, why the compiler know it should forward to

```
template<template<class...> class A, class... T, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>
```

and split class A into

```
template<class...> class A, class... T
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl;

template<template<class...> class A, class... T, template<class...> class B>
    struct mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>
{
    using type = B<T...>;
};
```

Here `mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>` is a partial specialization of `mp_rename_impl` struct template.

Then the compiler makes use of [partial ordering rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). Namely:

> When a class template is instantiated, and there are partial
>   specializations available, the compiler has to decide if the primary
>   template is going to be used or one of its partial specializations.
>
> 1) **If only one specialization matches the template arguments, that
>   specialization is used**
>
> 2) If more than one specialization matches, partial order rules are
>   used to determine which specialization is more specialized. The most
>   specialized specialization is used, if it is unique (if it is not
>   unique, the program cannot be compiled)
>
> 3) If no specializations match, the primary template is used

As you have only one specialization `mp_rename_impl<A<T...>, B>` and it matches the template arguments then it is picked up by the compiler.

The compiler compares `A<T...>` against `std::pair<int, double>` and `B` against `std::tuple` and deduces corresponding types: `A` as `std::pair`, `B` as `std::tuple` and `T...` as `int, double`.